# Multiple partial search statements in sql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently creating a simple person mySQL search using the following input searches:

status (This is an option list with a fixed value 1,2,3,4)
firstname
surname
email
phone
description

this is my current code:

```
if($stmt = $db_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE status = ?
OR firstname = ?
OR surname = ?
OR email = ?
OR telephone_mobile = ?
OR description = ?"))
{
   $stmt->bind_param('isssis',$post_status, $post_firstname, $post_surname, $post_email, $post_phone, $post_desc);
   $stmt->execute();
   $main = $stmt->num_rows;
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
}

<table>
<?php 
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->surname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->telephone_mobile; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->description; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } $stmt->free_result(); ?>
</table>
```

I understand that the `OR` statement is incorrect and I have been reading about `AGAINST` and `LIKE` statement and I'm unsure of the correct method as sometimes some of the input forms may be blank and others may be fully filled.

Any help would be great! :)

EDIT:

```
Example Data

firstname | surname | email           | phone         | description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
john      | smith   | john@me.com     | 07645362839   | he has a SIA licence
larry     | howden  | lh@google.com   | 01574830487   | he is a beautiful man
jane      | jones   |                 | 01937437384   | has no email address
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure LIKE won't do anything if the field is blank.

Comment: Can you also add an example of the result you want? Like a row in the database and some values that you want to be matched?

Comment: Ive added the result, which shows all rows based on result

Comment: I mean add actual data. Put an example with a row you have in the database and the values you want to match against

Comment: Sadly I'm running it locally, but all it is a single page with the search criteria on the left and records showing on the right

Comment: This is why full text searching was invented... on a large dataset, this is going to be pretty slow.

Comment: If you can't post an example of data to be used then i guess you're not going to receive much help.

Comment: To add to @JeremyHolovacs point, this also isn't going to be very accurate, what about fuzzy searching?  What about John vs Jon?

Comment: @AlexLinte I don't think much data is required to see that LIKE would be perfect for this situation...

Comment: Yes, LIKE can be part of the solution but unless he post what data he has and what should result, telling him to use LIKE won't help him much if he doesn't know how to use it properly.

Comment: @user1947561 I'm not concerned about varied spellings but thank you for reminding me about this potential issue.

Comment: Ok, now we're getting there. And you want to retrieve results that match partially any of the criteria if the values are not empty?

Comment: @AlexLinte I want the search to deal with partial matches and full matches but not break if a certain value is empty (I've also added on 'Jane' who has no email address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(!empty($post_status)) {
    $binds[] = &$post_status;
    $bind_type .= "i";
    $criteria[] = 'status = ?';
}
if(!empty($post_firstname)) {
    $post_firstname_val = "%".$post_firstname."%"; 
    $binds[] = &$post_firstname_val;
    $bind_type .= "s";
    $criteria[] = 'firstname LIKE ?';
}
if(!empty($post_surname)) {
    $post_surname_val = "%".$post_surname."%";
    $binds[] = &$post_surname_val;
    $bind_type .= "s";
    $criteria[] = 'surname LIKE ?';
}
if(!empty($post_email)) {
    $post_email_val = "%".$post_email."%";
    $binds[] = &$post_email_val;
    $bind_type .= "s";
    $criteria[] = 'email LIKE ?';
}
if(!empty($post_phone)) {
    $post_phone_val = "%".$post_phone."%";
    $binds[] = &$post_phone_val;
    $bind_type .= "s";
    $criteria[] = 'phone LIKE ?';
}
if(!empty($post_desc)) {
    $post_desc_val = "%".$post_desc."%";
    $binds[] = &$post_desc_val;
    $bind_type .= "s";
    $criteria[] = 'description LIKE ?';
}
if(count($criteria) > 0) {
    $query .= ' WHERE '.implode(" OR ", $criteria);
}

$stmt = $db_connect->prepare($query);
if(count($binds) > 0) {
    $params = array_merge(array($bind_type), $binds);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

For each non empty search criteria it will add a condition to match that criteria partially (or full if you enter the entire value).
This will return all rows that will match any of the conditions added to the search.

Lets say you have `$post_firstname = "Jane"` and `$post_pone = "0764536"`.

The code will return both the 1st row (since it will match the phone partially) and the 4th row since it will match fully the name.

Comment: I didn't even this of doing it this way! I'll give it a go!

Comment: Won't the bind_param cause an issue because its only been set once but could be multiple times $stmt->bind_param('s', $val);

Comment: I'm getting Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: I've edited my answer for the binding part. Let me know if it's ok now.

Comment: I got: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object

Comment: Also, have you considered using PDO instead of mysqli? PDO is a level heigher the mysqli and allows for dynamic variable bindings that would solve this problem. The syntax is the same.

Comment: Hi, I haven't tried PDO but if it makes it easier I would rather use it

Comment: I couldn't find many simple examples of usage so I didn't use it

Comment: Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

Comment: Brill thank you it works great! I think I will do some reading into PDO if you think its the better option :)

Comment: It is. For example in the above code, i could cut about 6 lines of redundant code for the binding part.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Linte! I really mean it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64069/discussion-between-joseph-gregory-and-alex-linte).

Answer (score 1):

I think that a lot of the comments are helpful, but not really needed.

If you want to use `LIKE`, you can simply change your query like this:

`SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE status LIKE 'status' OR firstname LIKE 'firstname'...`

You can use `LIKE` in place of an equals sign.  You can use a `%` if you want to include meta characters.

Comment: would a meta character need to be applied when searching for an email address?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know.  You could add it to be safe, though.  For example, `... "LIKE '%".$var."'" ...`